# Еще раз о логике работы Sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx, полнотекстовый-поиск

Я использую библиотеку PHP для сфинкса. Написал несколько источников в конфигурации sphinx.conf (статьи, новости, заметки).

После успешного поиска я получаю выходной массив в PHP с ключами (ID-ых) найденных строк из каждой таблицы (новости, статьи, сообщения).

Дальше мне что, нужно создать отдельный запрос по этим полученным ID для каждой из таблиц? Чтобы отобразить результат пользователю?

Но если выходной массив будет содержать более 1000 различных идентификаторов? Это будет 1000 запросов к БД?
Большое спасибо за любой замечание или объяснения!

**Один из источников описан так:**

```
source users : lsParentSource
{

    sql_query_range   = SELECT MIN(idDetailToUsers), MAX(idDetailToUsers) FROM detailtousers
    sql_range_step    = 128
    sql_query         = SELECT idDetailToUsers as id, 9 as type, UsersTypeAccount, idDetailToUsers, SpecializationName, DetailToUsersName, DetailToUsersPhoto, city, country FROM detailtousers join users ON users.idUsers = detailtousers.idDetailToUsers left join usersspecialization ON usersspecialization.UsersSpecializationIdUser = detailtousers.idDetailToUsers left join specializationtousers ON specializationtousers.idSpecialization = usersspecialization.UsersSpecializationIdSpecialization WHERE idDetailToUsers >= $start AND idDetailToUsers <= $end GROUP BY idDetailToUsers

    sql_attr_uint     = type
    sql_attr_uint     = idDetailToUsers
    sql_attr_uint     = UsersTypeAccount
    sql_field_string  = SpecializationName
    sql_field_string  = DetailToUsersName
    sql_field_string  = DetailToUsersPhoto
    sql_attr_uint     = city
    sql_attr_uint     = country

    sql_query_info    = SELECT idDetailToUsers, DetailToUsersName, UsersTypeAccount, SpecializationName, DetailToUsersPhoto, city, country \
                        FROM detailtousers WHERE idDetailToUsers = $id
    sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}
```

Если указать по Вашему примеру - то в выходном массиве я получаю название поля `type:`

```
 ["fields"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "type"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "specializationname"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "detailtousersname"
    [3]=>
    string(18) "detailtousersphoto"
  }
```

Но без типа(указания на таблицу) `Articles`

Пользуюсь расширением для **PHP(PECL) Sphinx.**

Код:

$s = new SphinxClient;
    $s->setServer("localhost", 9312);

```
$s->setMaxQueryTime(9000);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
//$s->setFilter('type', array( 9, 10) );

$result = $s->query($_POST['search'], '*');
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk Смотрите в мой [ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/385934#386147) **Update #2**.

Comment: Пробовал - результат такой же...поле получаю - а название - нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле то, что вами описано выше, в принципе рабочий вариант. Да, будет 1000, и вы будете работать с этой тысячей. Но только не нужно забывать про постраничную навигацию (и про то, что дальше 10-й заходят только ради "полистать" и их в принципе можно исключить), и тысячу запросов не нужно делать, все можно сделать одним запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id IN (4,9,6,2...)
```

Однако, чтобы сохранить релевантность, нужно чтобы этот порядок айдишников вывелся в том же порядке, что он был отдан sphix`ом. Для этого немного sql-магии:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id IN (4,9,6,2...) ORDER BY FIELD (id, 4,9,6,2...)
```

Но я за время работы с sphinx`ом приобрел собственную (а может, и нет) точку зрения работы с ней.

Sphinx позволяет хранить данные для вывода (агрегирование данные), как по тем полям, что делается поиск, так и по тем полям, что поиск не делается. Поэтому можно sphinx.conf настроить так, чтобы он вместе с id отдавал и другие поля - title, category_name, tags_name и т.д. и т.п. Страница результата поиска не требует подключения к БД в принципе. И у нас появляется возможность сделать крутой "autocomplete".

Comment: Спасибо за подробный и качественный ответ! Могли бы Вы привести пример одного из описанных источников в файле sphinx.conf? Чтобы понять, как настроить вывод полей? Сейчас у меня выходной массив от поиска не содержит ничего, чтобы указывало из какой таблицы полученные ID's, нужно хотя бы сделать выходное поле type, фиксированное значениями для каждого запроса.

Comment: Я заметил, что в результирующий массив от поиска попадают поля, которые описаны в конфиге как: `sql_field_string`, при этом есть `sql_attr_uint     = type`, которые не попадают в этой массив.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/VasyOk/9df7614fc6d101d40c2b - жутко старый конфиг, который я написал для теперь уже не работающего сайта, думал, что удалил.

Comment: @VasyOk

> по тем полям, по которым поиск не делается

Лучше не увлекаться, ибо всё это дело лежит в памяти. Правильной практикой будет хранить поля отличные от `string` с дополнительный запросом в БД, как, собственно, Вы и отметили выше. Исключением может быть сценарий, при котором необходимо вывести 1-2 поля с ограниченным числом символов (VARCHAR), к примеру, `title`.

@Oleg Ponomarchuk Предлагаю посмотреть мой конфиг для актуальной версии Sphinx 2.2.6 https://github.com/romeOz/rock/blob/master/tests/data/sphinx/sphinx.conf

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk Бывают случаи, когда здорово помогает использование sql_attr_multi (MVA). К примеру, если посмотрите на главную http://hashcode.ru/, то заметите, что в каждом сниппете вопроса имеется набор тегов. В случае [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system), это как правило связь M:M ("многие ко многим"). Sphinx с этой задачей справится быстрее нежели стандартные средства СУБД (JOIN-ы или несколько запросов). 
Вот ещё неплохая [статейка](http://chakrygin.ru/2013/04/multi-valued-attrs-and-joined-fields.html) про MVA.

Comment: Спасибо! Не совсем понял о:  `Правильной практикой будет хранить атрибуты отличные от string с дополнительный запросом в БД` и как мне определить от какой таблицы получены ID's чтобы сделать в них запрос на выборку? И можно ли этот запрос делать средставами Sphinx,

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk Написал в виде [ответа](http://hashcode.ru/questions/385934#386147).

Comment: Update #2 - все равно не получаю название таблицы в выходном массиве, только названия поля. Запрос: `$result = $s->query('mam', '*');`

Answer (score 3):

К примеру, нам нужно создать индекс по статьям (`articles_index`):

- Пример [конфига](http://pastebin.com/0yr9RyWb).
- Убиваем демон, который запустился после установки Sphinx: `sudo service sphinxsearch stop`
- Создаём индекс: `sudo indexer --config /path/to/sphinx.conf --all`

> Ошибок быть не должно. Разве что: `WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo` и WARNING на common_source - не обращаем внимание.

- Запускаем демон: `sudo searchd --config /path/to/sphinx/sphinx.conf`
- Коннектимся: `mysql -h0 -P9306`

  > -h0 - это localhost. -P9306 - порт, на котором весит Sphinx демон.
- Запрос в синтаксисе SphinxQL: `SELECT * FROM articles_index WHERE MATCH('тест');` Получаем массив id-ков.
- Собственно полученные id-ки вставляем в запрос `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN (4,9,6,2...)`, если нужно с соблюдением порядка, то: `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id IN (4,9,6,2...) ORDER BY FIELD (id, 4,9,6,2...)`

Как видно, мы делаем два запроса: к демону Sphinx (индекс `articles_index`), а  потом к СУБД (таблица `articles`).

> и как мне определить от какой таблицы получены ID's.

Думаю, я ответил на Ваш вопрос.

> И можно ли этот запрос делать средставами Sphinx

Из коробки Sphinx предостаялет API для различных языков, в том числе и для PHP. Как правило, все API хранятся `/usr/share/sphinxsearch/api/`. Копируйте `sphinxapi.php` в свой проект и подключаете. [Пример использования API](http://cyberville-project.ru/2010/11/sphinx-api-php-2-part2.html). Будьте внимательнее, статья за 2010 год. [Актуальная информация по API](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-reference).
Я лично пользуюсь [расширением для Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/extensions/sphinx), вернее данное расширение я внедрил в свой [Rock Framework](https://github.com/romeOz/rock/tree/master/framework/extensions/sphinx) с некоторыми изменениями.

Если Вы имели в виду, может ли Sphinx, получив ID's, самостоятельно делать запрос в СУБД - нет. Его задача индексация (делает порционный запрос к СУБД и складывает всё в индекс на диск, а некую часть держит в памяти - горячие данные индекса. Про [RT-индексы](http://blog.nagaychenko.com/2011/09/18/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-realtime-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-rt-%D0%B2-sphinx/) с полноценным [CRUD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) другая история) и поиск с выдачей ID's. В некоторых случаях, возможно, потребуется вывести и другие атрибуты (писал в комментариях).

#### Update #1

Результат в консоли:

[image]

#### Update #2

Вот [результат](http://pastebin.com/NnpZDnwb) использования `sphinxapi.php` (аналог PECL). Конфиг [sphinx.conf](http://pastebin.com/kp79iefG).
Как Вы могли заметить, результат поиска размещён в `matches`.

Некоторые замечания:

- Если `matches` отсутствует, значит ничего не найдено по Вашему запросу.

> Вместо `$_POST['search']` укажите "ручками" поисковый запрос.

- После любых изменений в `sphinx.conf` требуется переиндексация: `sudo indexer --config /path/to/sphinx.conf --all --rotate`.
- При использовании API (если конкретнее, то метода `SphinxClient::setMatchMode()`) мною замечена ошибка вида `Deprecated: DEPRECATED: Do not call this method or, even better, use SphinxQL instead of an API`. Как бы авторы в лице Аксёнова и Co намекаю, что использование API на текущий момент времени не является хорошей практикой. Используйте SphinxQL через обыкновенное PDO, а именно: http://pastebin.com/UABtVzys

Comment: В Вашем примере конфига составлен один источник, но без указания полей. Так же не ясно, как в выходном массиве определить, из какой таблицы получены ID's

Comment: > из какой таблицы получены

```
...
sql_query  =  SELECT id, title, 'articles' AS `table` FROM articles WHERE id >= $start AND id <= $end

sql_field_string = table
...
```
Подобное мне приходилось использовать исключительно для UNION-запросов.

Comment: Приведу в вопросе пример своего ресурса, не понимаю до сих пор этот момент

Comment: У меня таблица определена как: `sql_attr_uint = type` и почему-то не входит в результат

Comment: Romeo, может Вас попросить поделиться знаниями о Sphinx, а именно о типах атрибутах  `sql_attr_uint` и прочих основах?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk В своём ответе я разместил скрин результата с полем `type` - всё выводится.

Вы каким API пользуетесь, нативным (sphinxapi.php)? Приведите код, который Вам выводит массив `fields`.