# Корректная работа с циклом foreach при подключении к базе данных через PDO

Tags: pdo, php, полнотекстовый-поиск

Здравствуйте!

Никак не могу разобраться с циклом foreach. Необходимо перебирать массив, в котором слова поискового запроса, и выводить полученные результаты на страницу. Но после всей обработки поискового запроса функция `count()` мне выдаёт нулевое значение массива, в котором должны быть извлечены данные, соответствующие поисковому запросу.

Код обработчика такой:

```
if (isset($submit)) {
    if (empty($query) or strlen($query) < 6) {
        echo "<div class='search_title_attention'>Поисковый запрос не введён, либо он менее 3-х символов кириллицы<br>или менее 6-ти символов латиницы!</div>";
    } else { // Начало вывода
        print_r($query);
        $words = clearQuery($query);
        print_r($words);
        if ($select == 'all') {

            searchArticles($words);
            $count = count($array);
            echo $count;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<div class='search_title_attention'>Вы обратились к файлу без необходимых параметров!</div>";
}
```

Функции, которые используются:

```
/*Функция обрезки окончаний слов*/

function dropBackWords($word) {
    $reg = "/(а|я|о|е|ь|и|ы|ая|яя|ое|ее|ый|ать|ять|еть|уть|у|ю|ем|ешь|ете|ет|ут|ют|ал|ял|ала|яла|али|яли|ул|ула|ули)(\s|$)/ui"; //данная регулярная функция будет искать совпадения окончаний
    $word = preg_replace($reg,'',$word);
    return $word;
}

/*Функция уничтожения стоп-слов*/

function stopWords($query) { //тут мы обрабатываем весь поисковый запрос
    $reg = "/(^|\s)(а|без|более|бы|был|была|были|было|быть|в|вам|вас|весь|во|вот|все|всего|всех|вы|где|да|даже|для|до|его|ее|если|есть|еще|же|за|здесь|и|из|или|им|их|к|как|ко|когда|кто|ли|либо|мне|может|мы|на|надо|наш|не|него|нее|нет|ни|них|но|ну|о|об|однако|он|она|они|оно|от|очень|по|под|при|с|со|так|также|такой|там|те|тем|то|того|тоже|той|только|том|ты|у|уже|хотя|чего|чей|чем|что|чтобы|чье|чья|эта|эти|это|я)($|\s)/ui"; //данная регулярка отрежет все стоп-слова отбитые пробелами
    $query = preg_replace($reg,'',$query);
    return $query;
}

/*Функция подготовки поискового запроса*/

function clearQuery($query) {
    $query = stripcslashes($query);
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    $words = explode(" ",$query);
    $words = stopWords($words);
    $i = 0;
    $keywords = "";

    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $word = trim($word);
        $regv = '/^([а-я0-9]+)$/i';
        $count = (preg_match($regv, $word)) ? 6 : 3;
        if (strlen($word)<$count) {
            unset($word);
        } else {
            if (strlen($word)>8) {
                $keywords[$i]=dropBackWords($word);
                $i++;
            } else {
                $keywords[$i]=$word;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $keywords;
}

function dataToArray($data) {
    $array = array();
    while (($row = $data->fetch()) !=false)
        $array[] = $row;
    return $array;
}

function searchArticles($words) {
    $query_search = "";
    foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($words[$key - 1])) {
            $query_search .= " OR ";
            $query_search .= "(title LIKE '%' . $value . '%' OR text LIKE '%' . $value . '%')";
        }
    }

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=xxx; dbname=xxxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из бызы не прошёл. Напишите об этом администратору <a href='mailto:admin@torawhite.ru'>admin@torawhite.ru</a>.</p><br>ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM male_articles WHERE :query_search';
    $data = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $data->bindParam(':query_search', $query_search);
    $data->execute();

    return dataToArray($data);
}
```

Ещё прошу развеять сомнения насчёт подключения к базе данных - я так понимаю, что подключение нужно обязательно использовать в функции, обозначить подключение вначале самой страницы результатов не даст?

```
 echo $count;
```

Выводит 0, а должен найти запись. В поисковый запрос ввожу только то, что точно есть в базе данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> я так понимаю, что подключение нужно обязательно использовать в функции

Необязательно. Для простенького примера/наброска подойдёт и [лапша-код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), к примеру, чтобы разместить его здесь.

В Вашем же примере используется процедурный стиль, а потому: функции в PHP имеют локальную область видимости, т.е. [переменные извне недоступны](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php) (в том же Си или JS иначе).

Замечания:

- Используйте [полнотекстовый поиск](http://habrahabr.ru/post/40218/), который в MySQL доступен из коробки (для InnoDB с MySQL 5.6). Хоть какая-то релевантность будет.
- Вместо Вашего набора функций по нахождению базовой формы слова, используйте [phpmorphy](http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/) (копия на [github](https://github.com/heromantor/phpmorphy))
- Если не ограничены рамками [shared-хостинга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3), то настоятельно рекомендую использовать специализированные поисковые движки: [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) или [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). Оба инструмента всё вышеперечисленное умеют (быстрая индексация, поиск с учётом морфологии для многих языков) + различные плюшки: подсветка (highlight) ключевых слов и т.д.

  - Sphinx: написан на C++, [почитать статьи создателя, Андрея Аксенова](http://habrahabr.ru/users/shodan/). Из коробки имеет API для различных языков програмиирования, в том числе и для PHP, но рекомендуется использовать [SphinxQL](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-reference) (sql-подобный синтаксис запросов)
  - elasticsearch: написан на Java, [почитать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122531/)

> API/ORM последних можно встретить в различных фреймворках.

Немного ещё по Sphinx-у:

Если сумеете его всё же [установить/настроить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/385934#386147), то предлагаю воспользоваться [моей реализацией ORM](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-sphinx) (это актуальный форк расширения Yii2 оформленный в виде независимого модуля).

#### UPDATE #1

Теперь по Вашему коду:

У Вас ошибка в понимании, когда использовать двойные и одинарные кавычки (в смешали оба варианта): `"(title LIKE '%' . $value . '%' OR text LIKE '%' . $value . '%')"`

Должно быть:

```
$query_search .= "(title LIKE '%{$value}%' OR text LIKE '%{$value}%')";
```

Вы неверно используете параметризованные запросы. В запрос попадают небезопасные данные. Вы кладёте конструкцию запроса (условия после `WHERE`) в параметр, т.е.

```
$data->bindParam(':query_search', "OR (title LIKE '%жил%' OR text LIKE '%пёс%')");
```

**Как правильно:**

```
function calculateWhere($words) {
    $query = $params = array();
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($words as $value) {
        $placeholder = ":plh{$i}";
        $params[$placeholder] = "%{$value}%";
        $query[] = "(title LIKE {$placeholder} OR text LIKE {$placeholder})";
        ++$i;
    }

    return array(implode(' OR ', $query), $params);
}

function searchArticles($where, $params) {
    try {
        /*
         Все манипуляции с кодировкой пробуйте на простом запросе, к примеру,
         "SELECT * FROM male_articles LIMIT 10". необходимо добиться отсутствия 
         абракадабры в кириллице на выходе. Уже потом можно приступить 
         к работе с LIKE
        */

        // вначале попробуйте без указания кодировки "charset", потом charset=utf8 или же charset=cp1251
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=xxx; dbname=xxxx;charset=utf8", "xxx", "xxx");
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        /*
         Возможно, дополнительно потребуется добавить
         $encoding = 'cp1251'; // or utf8
         $pdo->exec("SET NAMES {$encoding}");
         $pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET {$encoding}");

         На текущий момент времени подобное не рекомендуется
        */

        $query = "SELECT * FROM male_articles WHERE {$where}";
        $sth = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute($params);
        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $sth->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из бызы не прошёл. Напишите об этом администратору <a href='mailto:admin@torawhite.ru'>admin@torawhite.ru</a>.</p><br>ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}

$query = 'жил был пёс';
$words = clearQuery($query);

// получаем условную часть запроса, которая идёт после WHERE и подготовленные параметры
list($where, $params) = calculateWhere($words);

// собственно, результат запроса
var_dump(searchArticles($where, $params));
```

#### UPDATE #2

> ...столько и файлов index.php

Нет, конечно:)

Вам необходимо почитать про [MVC](http://goo.gl/U71I9D)

- Организовать единую точку входа. [Конфиг для apache](http://pastebin.com/uhdPq6cs). Или [хабр-статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/115389/)
- В index.php (та самая точка) организуем [роутинг по урлу](http://goo.gl/WKyNfz). Под капотом ReqExp(регулярные выражения) для парсинга урла и иные правила (смотрит, в request заголоки), к примеру, Ajax запрос или нет.
- Последний направляет нас в соответствии с этими правилами в Контроллер (`PostController`) с action (`content`),т.е. `(new PostController)->content()`. Контроллер является связующим звеном между моделью и вьюхой. Как правило, должен содержать минимум бизнес-логики (существует порочная практика делать "толстые тупые уродливые контроллеры"). [Пример контроллера](http://pastebin.com/6wk7Wq00)
- Получаем данные из модели. Моделью может быть любой источник данных: БД, массив, файл, html-форма. Модель может иметь встроенный валидатор и санитизатор данных, к примеру, [в виде правил](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-models.md) ([статья на русском](http://reposlav.ru/yii2-model-rules/))

> По поводу, как обезопасить себя (SQL injection, XSS) я [недавно писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393450#393456)

- Отправляем данный во вьюху. В качестве вьюхи может выступать либо некий шаблонизатор ([Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/),...), либо нативный php. Кхм, можно воспользоваться моим [Rock Template](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-template): использует, как нативный php, так [MODx-подобный](http://modx.com/) синтаксис.
- PROFIT

**P.S. Но для начала позаботьтесь, чтобы у Вас была версия PHP не ниже 5.3, а лучше 5.4 и выше**, ибо подавляющее большинство инструментов используют [пакетный менеджер composer](https://getcomposer.org)

Comment: @Torawhite

> как минимум виртуальный выделенный сервер

Недавно [писал про возможные варианты за недорого](http://hashcode.ru/questions/393312#393376). Вполне возможно. что Вы платите больше 149 руб. в месяц.

Для использования phpmorphy не требуется выделенный сервер (словари в бинарниках). Так что, полнотекстовый поиск MySQL + phpmorphy вполне жизнеспособная связка на shared-хостинге.

Comment: @romeo с версией php попробую разобраться. А кодировку я указал AddDefaultCharset utf-8 в .htaccess. В самом начале выводились абракадабры. Читаю (http://habrahabr.ru/post/244561/) еще про phpmorphy, как Вы посоветовали. Смотрю, там кода больше раза в три.

Comment: @romeo У меня к Вам вопрос есть, немного отвлеченный от темы - я так понимаю, есть два метода вывода содержимого из базы в файл-просмотрщик. Тот же попов учил, например, передавать переменную id через адресную строку, файл её принимает и выводит нужные данные, так и у меня. Но, например, на хабре и других сайтах вижу папку (http://habrahabr.ru/post/244561/) То есть тут сколько статей столько и файлов index.php или тут какая-то другая реализация?

Comment: @Torawhite

> А кодировку я указал AddDefaultCharset utf-8 в .htaccess

Иногда этого [бывает недостатчно](http://goo.gl/cSGbSV). Вы простом запросе ` SELECT * FROM male_articles LIMIT 10` получаете валидную кириллицу или вопросы/абракадабру? 

У Вас всё получилось? Я писал Вам код не с чистого листа, а с апробацией у себя. Если по-прежнему выводится пустой массив, то забейте в базу тестовые данные на латинице и вместо поискового запроса `жил был пёс` вбейте на латинице. Если получили результат, то манипулируйте с кодировками. Да, и смотрите в ответ, я добавил комментарии к коду.

Comment: Сейчас все работает http://torawhite.ru/magazine/search_view.php?submit=&select=all&query=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BB+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%87 Выводится кириллица, посмотрите сами. Сейчас попробую сделать вывод SELECT * FROM male_articles LIMIT 10
Попробовал, выводится без проблем с кодиковкой

Comment: @Torawhite

> ...столько и файлов index.php

Дополнил ответ. 

Да, и мы с Вами нарушаем регламент хэшкода. Вопросы должны быть атомарны: один вопрос - один ответ.

И если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом) + можно ещё лайк.

P.S. Напишите мне на [почту](http://hashcode.ru/users/10551/romeo). Мне кое-что интересно.

Comment: @Torawhite У меня есть [абстракция над phpmorphy](http://goo.gl/hlLtZo) (умеет возвращать базовые формы слова, словоформы слова и подсветку ключевых слов). Пока она часть моего фреймворка. На данный момент все компоненты преобразую в модули, чтобы работали независимо от фреймворка. phpmorphy на очереди. Будет и документация по использованию. Единственное,все [мои инструменты](http://goo.gl/Icq4Ls) используют PHP 5.4. Я могу сделать исключение для phpmorphy понизив до 5.3.

Comment: @romeo лайк не даёт ставить, говорит, "не дорос"
@romeo по ссылке Ваш профиль, не могу там найти e-mail, вот мой torawhite@yandex.ru