# Непонятный foreach

Tags: php, база-данных, sql, foreach

Есть код.

```
$query = 'запрос к инфе в бд';

foreach($query as $row) {
     тут html код
}
```

Так вот, если в базе по запросу есть инфа, то все выводит как нужно. А если нет, то не выводит код html, который внутри цикла. Изначально инфы никакой нет в бд. А выводить html  должен, потому как там поля для добавления. Если в бд инфа есть, то в поля foreach выводит данные. Что делать?

Comment: вынести html с полями для заполнения за пределы цикла?

Comment: А так разве можно? Разве не должны данные выводимые при помощи foreach быть именно в нем?

Comment: @bobiq, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
<header>
...
</hedaer>

<content>
<?php
if (!$query) {
   echo 'Данные отсутствуют';
} else {
  foreach($query as $row) {
     тут html код
  }
}
?>
</content>
<footer>
...
</footer>
```

А вообще, мешать бизнес-логику с вёрсткой является дурным тоном.

Необходимо понимание принципа [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller). Почитайте [моё краткое изложение (начиная с UPDATE #2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400355#400410) этого паттерна.

**Обновление**

Тогда бы у Вас не должно было возникнуть данного вопроса. На уровне контроллера/экшена отслеживается отсутствие данных и выдаются шаблон-заглушка. Либо вариант, который я указал выше. В случае с `option`, то:

```
<select>
    <option selected>Выберите город...</option>
    <?php if ($rows): ?>
       <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
          <option value="<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif ?>
</select>
```

Данные, которые попадают в вёрстку, желательно экранировать/приводить к соответствующему типу (санитизировать). По умолчанию нужно никому не верить, даже своей БД или любому другому хранилищу данных. Подобной задачей как раз таки занимается шаблонизатор.

Comment: А я и не мешаю их. А как, по-вашему, выводить, например, нужно option из селекта? Или как в этом случае выводить данные из бд в поля. Ну сам запрос к бд я могу засунуть в модель, саму модель подключать в контроллер, а вот циклы типа for foreach while все равно в верстке прописывать придется.

Comment: romeo, спасибо. в принципе я с option так и делаю.

Answer (score 0):

Цикл foreach выполняется для каждой записи возвращенной запросом, если ничего не вернулось, то логично, что цикл ни разу не выполнится. Если он должен что-то выводить при пустом ответе, то и проверяйте ответ на пустоту и выводите что надо в этом случае.