# Как можно сделать ответ жирным шрифтом?

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно сделать ответ жирным шрифтом?

Вот php код:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['go'])) {
    $search = $_GET['go'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR url LIKE '%$search%' OR result LIKE '%$search%'") or die("Нет доступ!");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'Ничего не найден!';
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $title = $row['title'];
            $url = $row['url'];
            $result = $row['result'];

            $output .= "<div id='result'>
                            <div id='title'>
                                <a target='_blank' href='$url'>$title</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id='url'>
                                <a target='_blank' href='$url'>$url</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id='result1'>
                                ".$result."
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            ";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Например, запрос такой скачать и ответ, например, **скачать** через торрент можно так или есть другой php код?  
Пример http://go.mail.ru/search?fm=1&rf=go.mail.ru&q=скачать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ваш запрос небезопасен - привет, SQL Injection!

  `...LIKE '%$search%'...`
- Процедурный доступ к БД (`mysql_query`) ["морально" устарел](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) (внимательно читаем, что написано в красной рамке). Необходимо использовать [PDO с параметризованными запросами (prepared statements)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/).
- Используйте [полнотекстовый поиск](http://habrahabr.ru/post/40218/), который в MySQL доступен из коробки (для InnoDB с MySQL 5.6). Хоть какая-то релевантность будет.
- [Прочитайте мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400355#400410), который я давал ранее

По вашему примеру:

Простейшая санитизация

```
$search = strip_tags($_GET['go']);
```

Вариант с highlight предложил @dimka3210, либо чуть более гибкий подход подсветки целых слов:

```
$search = preg_quote($search, '/');
$title = preg_replace("/\b({$search})\b/iu", '<b>$1</b>', $row['title']);
```

[Пример работы](http://ideone.com/dFuvUu)

Идеально механизм подсветки слов работать не будет, ибо подразумевает точное совпадение. Требуется использовать морфологический анализ (нахождение словоформ слов). Для этого необходимо использовать специальные инструменты, к примеру, [phpmorphy](http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/) (копия на [github](https://github.com/heromantor/phpmorphy)). В общем, смотрите на последний пункт, я Вам привёл ссылку на ранее [данный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400355#400410).

Comment: @romeo, код работает, но есть минусы, например, индексирует только большой буквами или только маленький буквами. Есть другой вариант?

Comment: @KYRAN Исправил ответ, добавил флаг `i`:

    "/\b({$search})\b/i"

Comment: @romeo, как добавить utf-8 ?

Comment: @KYRAN Добавить флаг `u`:

   "/\b({$search})\b/iu"

Comment: @romeo, Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = $row['title']
```

меняете на

```
$title = str_replace($search, "<b>$search</b>", $row['title']);
```

и

```
$result = $row['result'];
```

меняете на

```
$result = str_replace($search, "<b>$search</b>", $row['result']);
```

Comment: @dimka3210, код работает, но есть минусы, например, индексирует только большой буквами или только маленький буквами. Есть другой вариант?